# Xcode shows empty blue rectangles instead of objects on some of the views

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode9

so far I tried:

> - restarting xcode
> - restarting my mac
> - Editor -> refresh all views
> - playing with the Editor -> Canvas options

here is an image, so you can see one view is OK, and next to it the broken view:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case (After upgarding Xcode version to 10.0) I just closed XCode and opened again and it became okay.

Answer (score 0):

for me - it was apparently a bug, I just added another label and moved it, and the view came back to life

Answer (score 0):

I had this experience with xCode 10, plus some icons and images not appear in some device, I tried to solve it by converting all image to sRGB profile, but it did not work, so I returned back again to xCode 9.4 version.

Comment: Yes, it's worked with me, and I realized a new version to AppStore.